# Record data type for heterogeneous Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, user-defined-types, structured-array

I am working with numpy and to create a heterogeneous array it is necesary to use dtype() function.
After read some python doc about this function I think I know how it works;

```
t = np.dtype([('name', str),('edad',int)]) <-- This tells to python that my array will have a new data type with a string named 'name' and an int named 'edad'.


R = np.array([('Rosendo',15)]) <-- And now everything I put with this other python will try to convert to str and int.
```

Is this the correct way to create heterogeneous arrays? My array items have to be always tuples?
I saw some people code like this:

```
t = dtype([('name', str_, 40), ('numitems', int32), ('price',float32)])
```

But but this not gonna work, what about the "40" on ('name', str_, 40).
Is there other ways to create heterogeneous arrays using dtype()?

Comment: See [Numpy: Structured arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html). Each dimension (think column), gets a name and a type. `x = np.array([('Rex', 9, 81.0), ('Fido', 3, 27.0)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])`. [SO: structured array questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structured-array).

Comment: This is a structured array, not a heterogenous array.

Comment: The array items *are not tuples* but the `np.array` constructor will require you to pass tuples if you want to create a structured array.

Comment: Thanks, and what is a heteronegenous array?

Comment: You can't use a 'generic' `str` in a compound dtype.  Is has to specify the length, e.g. 'U10`.

Comment: Give some context.  Where did you read about 'heterogeneous' array?  That's not a `numpy` term.

Answer (score 0):

To create a structured array you need to specify the compound dtype, and the data as a list of tuples:

```
In [98]: dt = np.dtype([('name', 'U10'),('edad',int)])                                               
In [99]: R = np.array([('Rosendo',15)], dtype=dt)                                                    
In [100]: R                                                                                          
Out[100]: array([('Rosendo', 15)], dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('edad', '<i8')])
In [101]: R['name']                                                                                  
Out[101]: array(['Rosendo'], dtype='<U10')
```

Often it is easier to specify data by field:

```
In [102]: R = np.zeros((3,), dt)                                                                     
In [103]: R                                                                                          
Out[103]: 
array([('', 0), ('', 0), ('', 0)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('edad', '<i8')])
In [104]: R['name'] = ['one','two','three']                                                          
In [105]: R['edad'] = [101, 93, 3]                                                                   
In [106]: R                                                                                          
Out[106]: 
array([('one', 101), ('two',  93), ('three',   3)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('edad', '<i8')])
```